# An elementary proof in Number Theory

Tags: elementary-number-theory

How can i prove this statement;

if $p$ is a prime then; $2^p - 1$ is divisible by no prime other than those of the form $2kp+ 1$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Observe that if $q$ is a prime such that $q|2^p-1$, then
$$
2^p\equiv1\pmod q
$$
Hence the order of $2$ modulo $q$ divides $p$,but $p$ is prime and the order is not $1$, so the order of $2$ modulo $q$ is $p$. Now we must have
$$
p|\varphi(q)=q-1
$$
As we wanted...